# How do I check if the year is valid entered by user?

Tags: python

I want to be able to check the year entered by user is valid:

- Only a positive integer
- Between the range 1998-current year

If no year is mentioned, then use the current year

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
from datetime import datetime

current_year = datetime.now().year

input_year = int(input("Enter Year Here >>"))

if input_year is None:
    input_year = current_year
elif (1998 > input_year) or (input_year > current_year):
    print("Please specify a date between 1998 to {}".format(current_year))
else:
```

Comment: What is more efficient than an simple if loop?

Comment: FWIW, in the current state of the code `input_year is None` can never be `True`

Comment: use chained condition when input is an integer `if 1998 < input_year < current_year`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I guess I have to run my program again, in this case, to be able to provide an input again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: @DeepSpace So how do I check if the input is empty?

Comment: @AlyssaAlex If the input is empty the `int(input(...))`  will throw a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the entered year is empty `int(input("Enter Year Here >>"))` will fail since you are trying to convert an empty string, so you need to take input in as a string, and check if string is None, if it is, then assign current_year to input year, otherwise convert input string to int

Other optimiziation you can do is chained comparison

```
from datetime import datetime

current_year = datetime.now().year
#Take input as string
input_year = input("Enter Year Here >>")

#If input is None, use current year, else convert input to int
if not input_year:
    input_year = current_year
else:
    input_year = int(input_year)

#Use chained comparison
if not 1998 < input_year < current_year:
    print("Please specify a date between 1998 to {}".format(current_year))
else:
    print("You are good")
```

Possible outputs are

```
Enter Year Here >>
Please specify a date between 1998 to 2019

Enter Year Here >>1990
Please specify a date between 1998 to 2019

Enter Year Here >>2020
Please specify a date between 1998 to 2019

Enter Year Here >>-1000
Please specify a date between 1998 to 2019

Enter Year Here >>2010
You are good
```

To keep checking for input, just wrap the code in a while true loop

```
while True:

    current_year = datetime.now().year
    #Take input as string
    input_year = input("Enter Year Here >>")

    #If input is None, use current year, else convert input to int
    if not input_year:
        input_year = current_year
    else:
        input_year = int(input_year)

    #Use chained comparison
    if not 1998 < input_year < current_year:
        print("Please specify a date between 1998 to {}".format(current_year))
    else:
        print("You are good")
```

Furthermore, you are use a string like `quit` to break your loop, and perhaps do your empty string check and input year assignment in a single line as well!

```
from datetime import datetime

while True:

    current_year = datetime.now().year
    input_year = input("Enter Year Here! Type quit to stop >>")
    if input_year.lower() == 'quit':
        break
    input_year = int(input_year) if input_year else current_year

    if 1998 < input_year < current_year:
        print('You are good')
    else:
        print("Please specify a date between 1998 to {}".format(current_year))
```

If you want to check if user inputs a string or a float, you can do try/except and rely on `ValueError` to check if the string can be cast to an int or not! If string can be cast as int, it won't throw a `ValueError`, otherwise it will

```
def check_int(s):

    is_int = False
    try:
        int(s)
        is_int = True
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return is_int

print(check_int('a'))
print(check_int('4.0'))
print(check_int(5))
```

The output will be

```
False
False
True
```

Finally, combining all of them we get

```
from datetime import datetime

def check_int(s):

    is_int = False
    try:
        int(s)
        is_int = True
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return is_int


while True:

    current_year = datetime.now().year
    input_year = input("Enter Year Here! Type quit to stop >>")
    if input_year.lower() == 'quit':
        break
    if not input_year:
        input_year = current_year
    elif check_int(input_year):
        input_year = int(input_year)
    else:
        print('Provide a number as year')
        continue

    if 1998 < input_year < current_year:
        print('You are good')
    else:
        print("Please specify a date between 1998 to {}".format(current_year))
```

The outputs will be

```
Enter Year Here! Type quit to stop >>
Please specify a date between 1998 to 2019
Enter Year Here! Type quit to stop >>hello
Provide a number as year
Enter Year Here! Type quit to stop >>-1234
Please specify a date between 1998 to 2019
Enter Year Here! Type quit to stop >>2000
You are good
Enter Year Here! Type quit to stop >>quit
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way I can check if the user only enters an integer and not, for example, a string or a float

Comment: Sure! Addd that part towards the end of the answer @AlyssaAlex

Comment: One last question, with the last part of your answer, it basically shows the ValueError even when I enter no input. I want to be able to skip this and make current year as the default. Could we merge these 2 somehow?

Comment: So if the user inputs string or float, or even no input,  you want to make current year as default @AlyssaAlex ?

Comment: If the user enters no input, then current year. The rest, show their respective errors.

Comment: What respective errors @AlyssaAlex Could you  explain ?

Comment: The year range, the type error if string float etc, the only positive integer. If no input, then current year.

Comment: Ohh I didn't mention any! Could you provide me some!

Comment: Mentioned it in my question :) For your answer, everything works but just that the ValueError is throwing an error because of an empty input. I just want to avoid that by specifying that an empty input will be considered as the current year. That's all, the rest is perfect.

Comment: Updated the answer to put everything together! Have a look @AlyssaAlex

Comment: Hi @AlyssaAlex please have a look at the updated answer, and if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick next to the answer :)